# GKE Container Registry Quota Exceeded

Tags: google-container-registry, google-kubernetes-engine

When deploying updates to Kubernetes hosts I am encountering the error "Quota Exceeded" but none of my Quotas in Google Console show as being exceeded (pictured below). Why is this happening?

```
kubectl describe pod c80b7631698

Events:
  Type     Reason                Message
  ----     ------                -------
  Normal   Pulling               pulling image "gcr.io/my-api:latest"
  Warning  Failed                Failed to pull image "gcr.io/my-api:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error: Status 429 trying to pull repository my-api: "Quota Exceeded."
  Warning  Failed                Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff               Back-off pulling image "gcr.io/my-api:latest"
  Normal   SandboxChanged        Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Warning  Failed                Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

[image: no exceeded quotas]

Comment: See also:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62141490/avoiding-error-409-quota-exceeded-while-working-with-google-cloud-registry

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are hitting "pull" quota.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have exceeded the [Quotas and limits for your Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/quotas). This quota is not listed on the quotas page as it is a fixed quota. If this is a recurring issue, I would suggest filling an issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com).

Comment: I'm definitely not exceeding 250,000 HTTP requests per day, and Container Registry uses Cloud Storage for each registry's underlying storage so that should be fine given my screenshot above.

Comment: Issue being tracked here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110285426